# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data using (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

I am getting SyntaxError with a message "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" pointing at the function "isAuthenticated" at:

```js
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jwt"));
```

Here is the complete code in my file:

```js
import {API} from "../../backend"

export const signup = user =>{
    return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

export const signin = user =>{
    return fetch(`${API}/signin`, {
        mthod: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

export const authenticate = (data, next) => {
    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
        localStorage.setItem("jwt", JSON.stringify(data));
        next();
    }
}

export const signout = next =>{
    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
        localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
        next();

        return fetch(`${API}/signout`, {
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(response => console.log("signout success"))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
};

export const isAuthenticated = () => {
    if(typeof window == "undefined"){
        return false;
    }
    if(localStorage.getItem("jwt")){
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jwt"));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Check what you're passing into the parser.

Comment: I guess you are passing not json to localStorage. Check it first your stringify output